# Qué reserva ensureCapacity de ArrayList en Polimorfismo

Tags: java

tengo este ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<>();
```

Tengo varias subclases entre ellas CuentaAhorro y CuentaCorriente. Cuenta es abstracta con dos métodos abstractos que implementan las subclases.

Tengo dos dudas:

Cuando una subclase redefine un método cualquiera, entonces en memoria, que se tiene, dos copias de cada uno de los métodos, uno de la superclase y otro de la subclase redefinido?

Y esto me hace pensar y aquí viene la otra duda, en el ArrayList cuando se hace ensureCapacity que se guarda anticipadamente en memoria, para objetos o instancias de Cuenta o una simple referencia a un objeto de tipo de Cuenta, por que qué sabe a priori de que objeto va a albergar si usamos el polimorfismo y le añadimos una referencia a un objeto de su subclase.

Gracias anticipadas.

Un cordial saludo.

Comment: Cuando sobrescribes los métodos de la clase padre, lo que pasa es que cada subclase tendrá única y exclusivamente los metodo que hay en la subclase. Segun he [leido](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_ensurecapacity.htm), el metodo `ensureCapactity` lo que hace es aumentar el tamaño de list. No hace nada mas,

Comment: Lo que guarda `ArrayList` es una lista con referencias a `Cuenta`, pero la implementación está hecha de manera que se va reservando espacio para los elementos de esa lista conforme se van incluyendo nuevos elementos. [`ensureCapacity(N)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity(int)) simplemente provisiona espacio para `N` elementos de manera previa, de modo que no se necesitará solicitar espacio para nuevos elementos hasta que no hayamos superado esos `N` elementos. PD: su funcionamiento no tiene relación alguna con el polimorfismo.

Comment: A ver, @kevinkevin, llevas unos días preguntando demasiadas cosas y no veo que leas lo que se te responde o, al menos, no lo demuestras aceptando (o no) las respuestas y tampoco dejas ningún comentario. Viendo tus carencias, sin ánimo de ofender, yo te recomendaría dos libros - **Thinking in Java** y **OCA & OCP Java SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide (Exams 1Z0-803 & 1Z0-804)**. Búscalos, léelos y verás como te aclaras muchas cosas. No es por no responder a tus preguntas pero tampoco se ve feedback por tu parte y es un poco frustrante escribir sin saber por qué. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

### En el `ArrayList`, cuando se hace `ensureCapacity()`, ¿qué se guarda anticipadamente en memoria?, ¿para objetos o instancias de `Cuenta` o una simple referencia a un objeto de tipo de `Cuenta`?

Desde el punto de vista de `ArrayList` los elementos que está almacenando son todos de tipo `Cuenta`, aunque en realidad se traten de `CuentaAhorro` o `CuentaCorriente`. He ahí la magia del polimorfismo.

Por otro lado, el tamaño en memoria de una referencia es independiente del tamaño real que ocupan en memoria los datos contenidos de una clase (de tipo genérico `Object` internamente), por lo que [`ensureCapacity(N)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity(int)) lo único que hace es reservar memoria para un número `N` de referencias a clases, ya sean de tipo `Cuenta` o cualquier otro tipo de clase: las referencias ocuparán lo mismo.

Aquí tienes unos enlaces a la implementación para que puedas ver cómo funciona internamente: [referencias](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L137), [`ensureCapacity()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L213) y la función real de crecimiento [`grow()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L229).